# Lightbox 2.6 questions on loading files

Tags: javascript

These are the first two steps from the instructions installing lightbox 2.6.  It says to load both from my HTML page. What HTML page? Also where do I load them: head, body, where?

> Look inside the js folder to find jquery-1.10.2.min.js and
>   lightbox-2.6.min.js and load both of these files from your html page.
>   Load jQuery first:
>
> Look inside the css folder to find lightbox.css and load it from your
>   html page:
>
> ```
> <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> What HTML page??

*Your* HTML page. You want the lightbox to appear in a page you've written, don't you? That's your page. (If you don't, then lightbox doesn't do what you think it does and you should find another tool).

> Also where do I load them - head; body, where?

Anywhere.